How to get count of local pending ops on Redis Database?
After updating to StackExchange Redis Client for .Net v2.7.33, we recently ran into an issue, where commands were getting queued up and not reflecting on the database. Cluster is setup to run as active-active cluster on Redis Enterprise 6.2. When we asked the server admin to check it, they ran the crdbtop command which showed that there were almost a million local ops pending and similar no of GC pending. I am wondering, if this pending local ops can be monitored via any client command from the StackExchange client for .Net? We are using .Net 6.
Thanks!
